# Azure Error. You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: asp.net, azure

When I navigate to my deployed azure website, I get an error,

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

**In my web.config**

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Full source code is [in my github](https://github.com/rberger247/EduSmart3). I  followed
[microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git) to deploy my app to azure. When I run my app locally , I have no errors.

Comment: Your Web API project doesn't have any controller. Does it work on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, I set the login page as the startup manually.

Comment: How are you doing it? I don't see that in your GitHub Repository.

Comment: Right click on the file and set as startup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

The root reason is that there is no default page in your Azure website.

You could directly view the page with following url, it should work.

```
https://{siteanme}.azurewebsites.net/views/login.html
```

Or you could **add** the [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents) in the project root folder and set it as default page in appsetting on the Azure portal and **save** the setting.

> The default document is the web page that is displayed at the root URL for a website.

[image]

Comment: A goof in my build process left me missing my index.html so I was missing a default document. Spent too much time researching my authentication settings before reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you may have deployed it in the wrong location. You may need to deploy your code inside site/wwwroot