# HTTP 403 Forbidden when published using Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I have published my asp.net website using Azure. After publishing it displays that the publishing was successful. But in the browser it displays HTTP 403 forbidden. I have tried IIS settings also. So how can I solve this issue??

Comment: It seems that there is no [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents) in your Webapp.

Comment: 403 is also the status code if you reached a quota limit. Which App Service Plan do you use?

Comment: @TomSun I have a default document (index.aspx). And I have configured it in IIS

Comment: @MartinBrandl I am using microsoft Azure

Comment: Thats not the answer to my question. Are you using IIS in a VM to host your application or do you host your App within an App Service Plan (PaaS)?

Comment: @MartinBrandl I am not using a VM trying to host it within the app service plan

Comment: @LasithJayalath What does **I have tried IIS settings also**  meaning? Would you mind sharing the error information with screenshot?

Comment: @TomSun in IIS I have enabled the directory browsing and added index.aspx as a default document

Comment: Do you mean that you [remote connection to azure webapp](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) and set the IIS? Index.aspx is in the azure default document list. Does the index.aspx  in the project root folder? If any error information screenshot, it will be  more helpful.

Comment: @TomSun I am trying to attach you a screenshot but unfortunately this don’t allow me for that. I have made index.aspx as the start page of the project. When I am running it in the local host it works accordingly. This is my first experience of hosting.

Comment: @LasithJayalath You could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018619/azure-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page/49021393#49021393) to check whether it is useful.

Comment: @TomSun It is working. Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned that it seems that there is no default document.

How to add the default document, you also could refer to an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49018619/azure-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page/49021393#49021393).